# Error in running android code on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

While running an android code in Eclipse,  I get an error saying "**Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
 Please check logcat output for more details.**". But I have declared Target SDKVersion = 11, MinSDKVersion = 3, MaxSDKVersion = 21. Version Code = 15 Version Name = 2.0

Comment: try increasing version code and version name

Comment: You can use also `adb install -r -d <link to apk>` or try to replace in your manifest.xml : `Version Code = 16 Version Name = 2.1`

Comment: thnx Apurva and Skizo.. increasing the versionCode and versionName worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error which you are facing is due to the **version code** of your application.
There is already a similar application of higher version installed in your emulator.

To resolve this issue, just uninstall the previous application from emulator or increase the **versioncode** of your application that is higher than the versioncode of the application installed in emulator.

Thanks.